# GWR: "Local R2" vs R2

Tags: geographically-weighted-regression

GWR:
What is the difference between "Local R2" and R2 is the result of GWR. In the output table, I have an R2=%70 but in another table, the maximum Local R2 has been reported as %21.

Comment: The local R^2 can be reported as the min, max or average R^2 of the local fits whereas the R^2 is an approximation of the total variation explained across the global model. Honestly, both of the values are a bit spurious. How is it even possible that you would have 49% more variation explained globally than you highest local fit? What software are you using? Perhaps they are fitting a straight linear model for the global.

Comment: Dear Jeffrey, GIS 10.7.1. Before GWR I tried Exploratory Regression, got no Passing model. From GWR the overall R2 was so low (%19). While multicollinearity was passed (all IVF were less than 7) and all 8 variables were above 90% significant, Jarque-Bera Statistic was significant (residuals are not normal), with high spatial autocorrelation (Moran test). After getting the map of std residual, I tried to get the coefficient table (B) but I continuously got an annoying error (999998) preventing me to get the table of raster results. I am confused and appreciate if you can give me some advice.